# VBA - Write all possible combinations of 4 columns of data

Tags: excel, vba, combinations

I've found script for writing all the possible combinations for 3 columns of data but am trying to modify the code to write 4 columns and possibly 5 and am not sure how. If anyone can help that would be great! I've tried doing what I think should work by adding in extra variables where they would follow (where I think they would go logically) but am geting a "Compile Error: Do without loop" that I cant explain.

Here is the code for the 3 columns (without my modifications) from User Excellll.

The description of the code is here:"This code will take the data from columns A, B, and C, and give the output you described in columns E, F, and G."

```
Sub combinations()

Dim c1() As Variant
Dim c2() As Variant
Dim c3() As Variant
Dim out() As Variant
Dim j, k, l, m As Long


Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range
Dim col3 As Range
Dim out1 As Range


Set col1 = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set col2 = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
Set col3 = Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))

c1 = col1
c2 = col2
c3 = col3

Set out1 = Range("E2", Range("G2").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3)))
out = out1

j = 1
k = 1
l = 1
m = 1


Do While j <= UBound(c1)
    Do While k <= UBound(c2)
        Do While l <= UBound(c3)
            out(m, 1) = c1(j, 1)
            out(m, 2) = c2(k, 1)
            out(m, 3) = c3(l, 1)
            m = m + 1
            l = l + 1
        Loop
        l = 1
        k = k + 1
    Loop
    k = 1
    j = j + 1
Loop


out1.Value = out
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 5 Columns

```
Sub combinations()

    Dim c1() As Variant
    Dim c2() As Variant
    Dim c3() As Variant
    Dim c4() As Variant
    Dim c5() As Variant
    Dim out() As Variant
    Dim j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long, n As Long, o As Long


    Dim col1 As Range
    Dim col2 As Range
    Dim col3 As Range
    Dim col4 As Range
    Dim col5 As Range
    Dim out1 As Range


    Set col1 = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    Set col2 = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    Set col3 = Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))
    Set col4 = Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown))
    Set col5 = Range("E1", Range("E1").End(xlDown))

    c1 = col1
    c2 = col2
    c3 = col3
    c4 = col4
    c5 = col5

    Set out1 = Range("G2", Range("K2").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5)))
    out = out1

    j = 1
    k = 1
    l = 1
    m = 1
    n = 1
    o = 1

    Do While j <= UBound(c1)
        Do While k <= UBound(c2)
            Do While l <= UBound(c3)
                Do While m <= UBound(c4)
                    Do While n <= UBound(c5) ' This now loops correctly
                        out(o, 1) = c1(j, 1)
                        out(o, 2) = c2(k, 1)
                        out(o, 3) = c3(l, 1)
                        out(o, 4) = c4(m, 1)
                        out(o, 5) = c5(n, 1)
                        o = o + 1
                        n = n + 1
                    Loop
                    n = 1
                    m = m + 1
                Loop
                m = 1
                l = l + 1
            Loop
            l = 1
            k = k + 1
        Loop
        k = 1
        j = j + 1
    Loop


    out1.Value = out
End Sub
```

For 4 Columns

```
Sub combinations()

    Dim c1() As Variant
    Dim c2() As Variant
    Dim c3() As Variant
    Dim c4() As Variant

    Dim out() As Variant
    Dim j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long, n As Long


    Dim col1 As Range
    Dim col2 As Range
    Dim col3 As Range
    Dim col4 As Range

    Dim out1 As Range


    Set col1 = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    Set col2 = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    Set col3 = Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))
    Set col4 = Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown))

    c1 = col1
    c2 = col2
    c3 = col3
    c4 = col4

    Set out1 = Range("G2", Range("K2").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4)))
    out = out1

    j = 1
    k = 1
    l = 1
    m = 1
    n = 1


    Do While j <= UBound(c1)
        Do While k <= UBound(c2)
            Do While l <= UBound(c3)
                Do While m <= UBound(c4)
                    out(n, 1) = c1(j, 1)
                    out(n, 2) = c2(k, 1)
                    out(n, 3) = c3(l, 1)
                    out(n, 4) = c4(m, 1)
                    n = n + 1
                    m = m + 1
                Loop
                m = 1
                l = l + 1
            Loop
            l = 1
            k = k + 1
        Loop
        k = 1
        j = j + 1
    Loop


    out1.Value = out
End Sub
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a generic approach which should work for any number of columns/values (within reason).

Example usage:

```vb
Sub ListCombinations()

Dim col As New Collection
Dim c As Range, sht As Worksheet, res
Dim i As Long, arr, numCols As Long

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
   'lists begin in A1, B1, C1, D1
    For Each c In sht.Range("A1:D1").Cells
        col.Add Application.Transpose(sht.Range(c, sht.cells(Rows.Count, c.column).End(xlup))) 
        numCols = numCols + 1
    Next c
    
    res = Combine(col, "~~")
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(res)
        arr = Split(res(i), "~~")
        sht.Range("H1").Offset(i, 0).Resize(1, numCols) = arr
    Next i

End Sub
```

Re-usable function:

```vb
'create combinations from a collection of string arrays
Function Combine(col As Collection, SEP As String) As String()

    Dim rv() As String
    Dim pos() As Long, lengths() As Long, lbs() As Long, ubs() As Long
    Dim t As Long, i As Long, n As Long, ub As Long
    Dim numIn As Long, s As String, r As Long, v, tmp()

    numIn = col.Count
    ReDim pos(1 To numIn)
    ReDim lbs(1 To numIn)
    ReDim ubs(1 To numIn)
    ReDim lengths(1 To numIn)
    t = 0
    For i = 1 To numIn  'calculate # of combinations, and cache bounds/lengths
        'handle cases where only one value in a column (not passed in as array)
        If Not TypeName(col(i)) Like "*()" Then
            ReDim tmp(1 To 1)
            tmp(1) = col(i)
            col.Remove i
            If i > col.Count Then
                col.Add tmp
            Else
                col.Add tmp, before:=i
            End If
        End If
        lbs(i) = LBound(col(i))
        ubs(i) = UBound(col(i))
        lengths(i) = (ubs(i) - lbs(i)) + 1
        pos(i) = lbs(i)
        t = IIf(t = 0, lengths(i), t * lengths(i))
    Next i
    ReDim rv(0 To t - 1) 'resize destination array

    For n = 0 To (t - 1)
        s = ""
        For i = 1 To numIn
            s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, SEP, "") & col(i)(pos(i)) 'build the string
        Next i
        rv(n) = s

        For i = numIn To 1 Step -1
            If pos(i) <> ubs(i) Then   'Not done all of this array yet...
                pos(i) = pos(i) + 1    'Increment array index
                For r = i + 1 To numIn 'Reset all the indexes
                    pos(r) = lbs(r)    '   of the later arrays
                Next r
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next n

    Combine = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the quick reply - is there anything that I need to do prior to running the code? I've tried running it and it seems to hang up (for me) on the "Next i" after the 'build the string' comment

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you update this code for columns with one value?

Comment: @resw67 - should be fine now

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to Regenerate all  possible combination (Using Recursion)

```
Public NextLevel As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    NextLevel = 1
    Call rrd(1, ActiveSheet.Range("F5"), 1, "")
End Sub

Public Function rrd(initiator As Integer, lim As Integer, NextLeg As Integer,     CreatedComb) As Boolean

    If initiator = lim Then
      ActiveSheet.Range("G" & NextLevel) = CreatedComb & "," & initiator
      NextLevel = NextLevel + 1
    Else
      If NextLeg < lim Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("G" & NextLevel) = CreatedComb & "," & initiator
        NextLevel = NextLevel + 1
        Call rrd(initiator + 1, lim, initiator + 1, CreatedComb & "," & initiator)
      End If
      Call rrd(initiator + 1, lim, initiator, CreatedComb)
    End If

End Function
```